# Novel involving escaping, clones and search for identity read about 20 years ago

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel I read about 20 years ago at a library.

It was about a young man called Ian (AFAIR, but I believe it was translated to French so the names could have been changed) which has to flee hostile forces. During his escape he discovers that he is the son of some public enemy/conspirationist/revolutionary named Drebber. This opponent also leads some faction which members are called "drebberists".

The young man is pursued by a pair of presumably cloned cops, even if cloning is banned in this futuristic society.

At some time in the story, I remember he meets a girl and they hide in a deserted mall/supermarket.

In the end, he realizes that he might not be the son of Drebber but a very clone of him, created as a backup to the leader of the opposition, should he get killed/disappear.

FWIW, I fuzzily remember the cover was beige/brownish with a winged figure (some sort of angel ?) in bright colors (green, blue and magenta). But I'm not sure (I read many books at that time) and since there may be several editions, in different countries I doubt this can be used as guidance. For example, a google image search for "Forever War" from Joe Haldeman yields many different covers, and the one I read appears only in French.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, you say this was a book? Was it a novel? Novella? Short story? etc.